# c# how to use a previously created instance of a class from a new class

Tags: c#, class, object, instance

im learning c# by reading tutorials and making my own programs, and I'm facing the next scenario, i will be using an example:
I created a Class in a different file and made an instance of it in form1 to fill it's propierties, ie:

```
 //Person.cs file
public Class Person
{
string name;
int age;
}

//Form1.cs file
... //I create the instance:
Person newPerson = new Person();
...
newPerson.name = textBox1.Text;
newPerson.age = textBox2.Text;
```

now, I have this third Class in a separated file(toSQL.cs), wich has a method that stores values into an SQL, but the only way I know to use an instance of the Person Class is by making a new one.
How can I access from the SQL Class to proprerties in Person Object made in Form1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your instance of `Person` to your `ToSQL` class via a method.

For example.. perhaps you also have this in your Form1 file:

```
ToSQL _sql = new ToSQL();
```

..and your `ToSQL` class has this method:

```
public int SavePerson(Person p) {
    /*
     * "p" in this method refers to the instance of Person you
     *  passed in from Form1
     */

    // This is where your SQL code goes ..

    return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You could then pass the `Person` instance to this method .. like this:

```
int result = _toSql.SavePerson(newPerson);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't know i can do that, finally it is:

Class ToSQL
{
               public void writeToSQL(Person somePerson)
               {
               //SQL Things...using thisPerson.name and thisPerson.age

               }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of your third class, provided that this class is not a `static` one, in your Form's code. Then you could call any method your want.

I **assume** that you have a configuration like this:

```
// This should be the handler for the save button.
// A button, which when will be clicked a new Person should be inserted in    
// the database.
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here we create a new Person object.
    Person person = new Person();
    person.name = textBox1.Text;
    person.age = textBox2.Text;

    // Here we create an instance of the ToSQL class.
    // This is the class, whose definition is in the toSQL.cs file 
    ToSQL toSql= new ToSQL();

    // Here we call a method called SavePerson, which inserts a new
    // Person in the database.
    toSql.SavePerson(person);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I gather that Form1.cs contains a reference to Person. And you want ToSql.cs to also be able to reference that same Person.

So how are ToSql.cs and Form1.cs currently wired up?  Does Program.cs create both of them?

Could you declare an instance of ToSql within Form1.cs? Then you could pass Person into ToSql within Form1.cs.

Comment: This answer has more questions than the question itself. Perhaps you should make a comment instead?

Comment: I made an instance of ToSql.cs in Form1 too, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it. I could finally pass Person properties to ToSql as @Simon Whitehead said. Thanks!